# Codeigniter Inner join query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I've written the following Inner joing query that works perfectly.

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM StockMain INNER JOIN StockDetail ON StockMain.vrnoa = StockDetail.vrnoa WHERE StockMain.vrnoa = ' . $vrnoa);
```

Then I thought to transform it to the following:

```
$query = $this->db->select('StockMain.*, StockDetail.*')
              ->from('StockMain')
              ->join('StockDetail', 'StockMain.vrnoa = StockDetail.vrnoa', 'inner')
              ->where('StockMain.vrnoa', $vrnoa);
              ->db->get();
```

But due to some strange reason it isn't working. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here. Why does this second query not work as both are the same?

Comment: If you print out the executed query ( `echo $this->db->last_query()` ) does it look correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to remove "**->db**" from last line.
So your query will be

```
$query = $this->db->select('StockMain.*, StockDetail.*')
              ->from('StockMain')
              ->join('StockDetail', 'StockMain.vrnoa = StockDetail.vrnoa', 'inner')
              ->where('StockMain.vrnoa', $vrnoa);
              ->get();
```